# CSS Padding / margin not showing inFirefox

Tags: css

I have the following CSS for a `div` in my CSS.

```
.floating {
        width: 500px;
        position: relative;     
        border:2px solid;
        border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px; /* Firefox 3.6 and earlier */
    background-color: #000000;
/*      margin-top: 50 px; */
/*      margin-left: 80px; */
/*      margin-right: 750px; */
/*      margin-right: 100 px; */
    padding: 10 px;
}
```

It was showing fine in Chrome with the margins enabled (now disabled) but Firefox was not recognizing margins at all. Firebug showed the CSS but without any of the margin tags. I took a quick solution by replacing the margins by paddings in the parent container which solved this issue.

However, I now see that padding is not showing either. If I add the padding parameter manually in Firebug, it shows just fine. What am I missing here ??

Comment: The code you posted does not enable us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Despite the obvious CSS mistakes, Jeroen is correct.  You should have posted the HTML along with the CSS at a minimum.  Adding a jsFiddle would have been a bonus.

Comment: Oops...the floating was a typo... its actually .floating

Comment: @Sparky672's answer was spot on. See... you didn't need the HTML after all. Thanks for the downvotes anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two problems...

1. `floating` is not properly defining or targeting anything.  There's no such HTML entity called `floating`.  If it's a class name it needs to be `.floating` and if it's an element `id`, it needs to be `#floating`.
2. Units must not contain a preceding space.  It should be `10px`, **not** `10 px`.  You seem to have made this same mistake in several places.

Comment: he wrote that it works in Chrome so i though that this is only bad copied.

Comment: @Sajmon, all we have to go on is what the OP has posted.  Sometimes bad code works in some browsers.

Comment: Yeah, for example IE, so it's right because i tried it on FF and all margins work so problem is in bad created CSS.

Comment: It WAS the unit spacing. Stupid mistake... the missing "." was a typo here. @Sparky672 is right. It still works in Chrome for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

In your class definition the class name ("floating") is missing the "." before it.  You also shouldn't have a space between the pixel count and unit.  In other words "10px", not "10 px".

Comment: How do you know it's a class name? It could be an `id` and missing the `#` before it.